# Split up summary data and resummarise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a summary df that looks like this:

```
Apples             100
Bananas            34
Kumquats           54
Greengages         101
Apples;Kumquats    5
Bananas;Greengages 7
```

And I want to simplify it by splitting up the counts for combined fruit into individual items:

```
Apples             105
Bananas            41
Kumquats           59
Greengages         108
```

i.e. I've dropped rows like `Apples;Kumquats` but increased both `Apples` and `Kumquats` by `5`.

Is there a good way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split values by `;`, reshape by `stack` and aggregate `sum`:

```
print (df)
                    a    b
0              Apples  100
1             Bananas   34
2            Kumquats   54
3          Greengages  101
4     Apples;Kumquats    5
5  Bananas;Greengages    7

df1 = (df.set_index('b')['a']
         .str.split(';', expand=True)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='c')
         .groupby('c', as_index=False)['b'].sum())
print (df1)
            c    b
0      Apples  105
1     Bananas   41
2  Greengages  108
3    Kumquats   59
```

Or solution with `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b']):
    for x in a.split(';'):
        d[x] += b

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list(d.keys()), 'b':list(d.values())})
print (df)
            a    b
0      Apples  105
1     Bananas   41
2    Kumquats   59
3  Greengages  108
```

Comment: This looks really good. The first option (using Stack) especially so. I'm trying to work it into my real-life examples.

If it's not too much trouble, can I ask how the solution would change if the column 'a' is actually the index of my dataframe?

Comment: @user4896331 - no, it is column, if it is index in `Series` only change `df.set_index('b')['a']` to `df`

Comment: I did it! Thank you. It takes me ages to work out how these incredibly clever functions are working, but I got it working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) setting `;` as a separator and multiply with the corresponding quantity:

```
df.food.str.get_dummies(sep=';').mul(df.quantity.values[:,None]).sum()

Apples        105
Bananas        41
Greengages    108
Kumquats       59
dtype: int64
```

---

Input data:

```
print(df)
           food          quantity
0              Apples       100
1             Bananas        34
2            Kumquats        54
3          Greengages       101
4     Apples;Kumquats         5
5  Bananas;Greengages         7
```

Comment: Thank you! How does this work if 'food' is actually the index and not a column?

Comment: You just need a `reset_index` in such case @user4896331 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.get_dummies`, transpose, and then multiply by the count, which will broadcast across the dataframe:

```
(df['fruit'].str.get_dummies(';').T * df['count']).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Apples        105
Bananas        41
Greengages    108
Kumquats       59
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([[x, s[s.index.str.contains(x)].tolist()] for i in s.reset_index()['index'].str.split(';').values.tolist() for x in i]).apply(lambda x: [x[0], sum(x[1])], axis=1).drop_duplicates()
            0    1
0      Apples  105
1     Bananas   41
2    Kumquats   59
3  Greengages  108
>>>
```